# Input tag is not taking any text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a login form in my React project for the very first time, the code is as follows and i am not able to enter anything, even the text cursor is not visible in the area.

Here is the code:

```
const Login = () => {
  return (
   
    <div>
    <>
    <Navbar/>
    <Background/>
    </>

    
    <div className='container'>
    <div className='header'>
        <div className='text'>Login</div>
        <div className='underline'></div>
    </div>
    <div className='inputs'>
        <div className='input'>
            <img src={email_icon} alt="" />
            <input type='email' placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
        <div className='input'>
            <img src={password_icon} alt="" />
            <input type='password' placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="forgot-password">Forgot your Password? <Link to='/reset_pw'>Reset password</Link></div>
    <div className="submit-container">
        <div className='submit'><Link to="/register">Register</Link></div>
        <div className='submit'>Login</div>
    </div>
    
</div>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <Footer />

</div>
```

**ChatGPT** said there might be a problem with the rendering of components or something might be clashing in the stylesheet, but I have no clue what is going wrong.

Comment: your code is completely fine, but you should share your `Background/>` component code . Maybe there some wrong css so background component element is above your this provided component